# How to import an SMS.txt file into the SMS.db file on iphone ios 6

Tags: iphone, merge, ios6, sms, extract

I am trying to merge 2 sms.db files in 2 separate backups made of my iphone 4S running ios 6.0.1.

I have used **iBackupBot for iTunes r24 for XP** to export the sms.db file of the older backup into a sms.txt (text file). Now I need to import this text file, and append to the newer sms.db file. Every post I have seen has sms's taken out of the iphone directly or extracted from the backup files, but none I have seen, to import back (a **text** file) to **merge** with the existing sms.db file ...

Any solution to even concatenate 2 sms.db files will also be appreciated ...

ps. After exporting the sms.db file (using iBackup) to the computer, I have tried using "**SQLite Database Browser v.13**" for WinXP to see the *.db file, but I don't see any database items at all ...

Answer (score 0):

Tryed to do same operation, it is not so easy. There are too much differences between DB format (iOS5 & iOS6), please see detailed info - http://linuxsleuthing.blogspot.ru/2012/10/whos-texting-ios6-smsdb.html

For view any DB you could use this free plugin for Firefox - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Try a program called Backuptrans iPhone SMS Backup & Restore.

Comment: Can you add an explanation of how this works/helps. We want this site to be a reference, not a bibliography.

Comment: This should be placed as a comment not an answer.